# How to programmatically suppress specific locale in Android application

Tags: android, internationalization, locale

All we know that Android application is highely customizable with respect to support of different locales. In my case my application currently supports 6 locales and everything works smooth. Whenever user selects phone locale, application switches to another locale and all menus, messages are in local languages.

Now question is in my desire to programmatically suppress specific locale(s) in application, since I'm going to distribute application in different countries using different channels, pricing policies and so on (not always through Android Market). So if application is intended for let say China - user couldn't switch locale to English or French.

Most simple way is just remove other locale resources from application - I understand that. But from point of source maintenance it's not very comfortable, so I would prefer to have some programmatic way for declining/suppressing of some locales in application.

Any ideas?

Comment: means you to set locale from your whole application?
and select your locale all the data are in selected language???
that all are u want programmatically???

Comment: @MiteshTechMe: did you read post carefully? If not - please read again

Comment: as far as i know, you have to go manual. you can use MiteshTechMe's code to reset the (not supported)locale within your application (in a way you can suppress other locales.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use this code...

```
    private void callSwitchLang(String langCode) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(langCode);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
            getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics()); 
onCreate(null);
}
```

In that mothods u pass your selected language code....

Comment: what is the **onCreate(null);** in your response.

Comment: onCreate(null); is use to reset your application...
when u call onCreate(null); than application change yr selected language to application...

Comment: had a hunch, so it is a hack through the life cycle. i knew this approach but the onCreate(null) was new. Thanks! for your response.

Comment: @MiteshTechMe: your code means that I can change locale to desired one and reload necessary resources. But what to do if user changes locale of phone? How can I intercept this event, otherwise application will load locales set by user, huh?

Comment: By using this code application locale will change...
after that if user change device locale tht's doesn't matter to application.....

Comment: Instead of calling onCreate() I call my function which does: setContentView(), findViewById()s etc. By calling onCreate() I get an error.

Comment: As of API level 17, you should use `config.setLocale(locale);` instead of `config.locale = locale;`. This will ensure that the layout directionality will be properly updated if you happen to switch between left-to-right and right-to-left locales.