# Multiple Language Android Application

Tags: android

I've made an application and the users love it, but they keep asking to provide it on other languages like whatsapp.

And I know about the localization on android but I want to make the language selection as an option to the user.

So how I can make my application multiple language? the user should be able to choose the language that he wants.

Does anybody knows the RIGHT WAY to do this, and if you have any links for tutorials.

Comment: Selecting the language shouldn't the users choice. Just go with the language, *they* chose in the first place on their Device.

Comment: sometimes its better to provide the application with the ability to select the language of the application

Comment: Why would they choose a language that they already haven't chosen for their phone? Why would a user want his phone to use German, but your app to be in Spanish? This makes no sense.

Comment: Duplicate of [how to get string from different locales in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475589/how-to-get-string-from-different-locales-in-android) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10874589/can-i-access-to-resources-from-different-locale-android and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357417/how-to-programmatically-suppress-specific-locale-in-android-application and others. All that being said, I would start by simply offering your app in other languages, and worry later about allowing the user to override the device default, as few apps truly need that.

Comment: a lot of users they have their mobiles language set on English, but when using a sensitive applications like banking they prefer to view it in their mother language, they just wont go with English (Selected Language on the Mobile), and if you asked the user to change his mobile language every time he uses your application it will be stupid.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for the link, I'll check if it works.

Comment: i think you will provide your project with the languages you need then by using the preferences and checking it in application starting to get the preferred language for the user

Comment: Just my 2c: If an application offers some languages (english, spanish, chinese) and I have set my device to german I may prefer spanish over chinese or english.